# permission denied when running wordpress from vagrant

Tags: wordpress, mamp, vagrant

I'm migrating from MAMP to Vagrant and I already have a wordpress installation under my existing MAMP documentRoot, I've mapped my MAMP docroot to my Vagrant docroot, everything works fine, but when I try to open my wordpress installation from the browser I get:

```
Warning: fopen(/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/temp-write-test-1394060868): failed to open
stream: Permission denied in /var/www/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 905
```

Also tried (from vagrant) to `chown -R www-data:www-data *` but it didn't work, the owner remains as 'vagrant'

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed! It was enough setting

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :owner=> 'www-data', :group=>'www-data'
```

in the vagrantfile, then `vagrant halt` and `vagrant up` to reboot the machine.

Comment: Totally life saver ;)